# What hooks are needed to bind a tag to a reusable block?

Tags: tags, block-editor

What do I need to hook or filter to associate a tag with a reusable block such that when the block is used the tag is added to the post (and, ideally, removed if/when the block is)?

I'm thinking specifically of the way Wikipedia has categories as part of templates. For example, a page with the "needs citations" message adds the page to "pages needing citation".

I am specifically interested in learning what parts of the API to talk to in order to make this happen.